# i am running this code in linux terminal but why getting this error?

Tags: mysql

my code:

```
CREATE table arp_table
(
time VARCHAR(30),
source_mac VARCHAR(30),
destination_mac VARCHAR(30),
source_ip VARCHAR(30),
destination_ip VARCHAR(30),
length VARCHAR(30),
);
```

error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ')' at line 9

Comment: you have extra `,`

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma in the line containing length VARCHAR(30), remove the comma from this line. The query will be like this

```
CREATE table arp_table
(
time VARCHAR(30),
source_mac VARCHAR(30),
destination_mac VARCHAR(30),
source_ip VARCHAR(30),
destination_ip VARCHAR(30),
length VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `comma` in your query.

```
CREATE table arp_table ( time VARCHAR(30), source_mac VARCHAR(30), destination_mac VARCHAR(30), source_ip VARCHAR(30), destination_ip VARCHAR(30), length VARCHAR(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct table create syntax. You put an extra `,` before last `)`

```
CREATE table arp_table
(
time VARCHAR(30),
source_mac VARCHAR(30),
destination_mac VARCHAR(30),
source_ip VARCHAR(30),
destination_ip VARCHAR(30),
length VARCHAR(30)
);
```

**N.B**: Always try to read the **ERROR** message properly. It'll help you to solve your problem own.